# Calculate resistor value of Optocoupler & Transistor

Tags: relay, module

I have a problem working out the values for the resistors R1 & R2 of a relay module.
Right now, I use R1 = 1k & R2 = 560 Ohm, but that is not working.

What resistor values should I use? And how can I calculate it?

[image: schematics]

i try to mimic 4ch relays module but not working.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following should give you a good start:

$$ R_1 = \frac{3V - V_{FW,input} - V_{FW, LED}}{I_{FW}} $$

and

$$ R_2 = \frac{5V - V_{CE,output} - V_{BE, 2N5551}}{I_{FW} \cdot CTR} $$

Inserting some values (from the datasheets):

$$ R_1 = \frac{3V - 1.4V - 1.2V}{5mA} = 80 \Omega \approx 82 \Omega $$

$$ R_2 = \frac{5V - 0.2V - 1V}{5mA \cdot 0.5} = 1520 \Omega \approx 1.6k\Omega $$

I have to warn you that you have two LEDs in series and the supply voltage is relatively low to supply them. I considered a voltage drop of 1.2V across the second LED which might be actually higher.

Answer (score 1):

Generically, I would work the problem right to left.

1) Start with the current that's required to pull in the relay.

2) Divide that current by the worst case (minimum) current gain of the 2N5551; Mutiply that current by 2X or 3X to ensure the transistor is in saturation.  Call this Ib, which is the base current needed to drive the transistor.

3) Divide Ib by the worst case (WC) CTR of the opto.  This gives you the minimum input diode current needed.  Call this Icr

4) Now that you know Icr, you use the worst case forward voltage drops of the opto's diode and the LED, along with your supply voltage to figure out the value for R1.

As others have said, given the WC forward drops for the opto and the LED, you do not have enough overhead with a 3.3V input to be able to reliably drive the opto, given the schematic you showed.

Answer (score 0):

3V of Vin is too low: forward voltage drop for one LED is about 1.8...2.5V, so two LEDs in serial will not work below 4...5V of Vin.

Better solution is connecting the LED in parallel to relay coil - of course witch resistor in serial to LED. Resistor 1k will be good for this in both places: in serial with input (R1), and this additional resistor in serial to LED connected in parallel to coil.

NOTE: even if the voltage drop on both LEDs in your original circuit will be slightly below 3V, this is not good solution because there will be too low voltage margin. So, even if you calculate the resistance for 3V, the input current will too strongly depend to Vin, resulting in non-reliable work in case of (incidental) lowering Vin. This is not good practice of design.